# How much text can UITextView hold?

Tags: pagination, uitextview

I have an uneditable `UITextView` that displays user-entered text.

What happens if the text is very long? Will it crash my app?

Should I paginate the text? How do iPhone web browsers like Safari, Chrome, or Firefox handle this issue?

Is there something like `UITableView` functionality for `UITextView`?