# How much text an EditText can display or hold in it?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Before some one close this due to the reason that it may have been asked earlier kindly read the following note

**Note: Another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523190/how-much-text-can-uitextview-hold) with almost same scope of information and usage has been asked earlier but it does not contain any answer! Tried googling a lot but did not find any satisfactory answer!**

My Question is about the EditText in android, how much text it can hold in it?
I write a code of server which receives a request from clients and display the history of all requests received so after 2650+ requests my app begin to not respond and finally crashes. I noticed that due to some reason very large text makes the EditText unresponsive one request contains almost 85 chars data!
Platform Nokia 6.1 with Android One 9.0 Pie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should not be any real limit, but as you see you may run out of memory or require too much computation power.

My advice: Load the visible partof the log you want to inspect / edit.

Eclipse starts "scalability mode" when you have more than ~ 5k lines of code.

WhatsApp and Telegram only show the latest ~50 messages, but quickly load more when you scroll up a lot.

9Gag, Facebook etc. will load more posts on demand.

So you should think about something like that, or google scalable textEdit solutions. My advice would be to store the logs in separate files and load dynamically.

Comment: Yes now i got it the biggest mistake of mine i am disposing all objects properly but as you said not scaling the text as per reading requirement which puts load on ram  . .thanks your advise solved my problem!